# tikz : edge loop and rotate

Tags: tikz-pgf, node-connections

Here is my example :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\test#1{\node[circle,draw](#1) at (0,0) {#1}; \draw[->] (#1) edge[in=40,out=-40,loop] ();}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \test{A}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)},rotate=90]
    \test{B}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get :

[image]

B is only A inside a scope with rotation. I would like to understand how to fix my loops in such a scope, so they could be shifted/scaled/rotated as expected : I want B to be exactly like a rotated A.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

I don't know why, but it seems that the `out` angle is not affected by the rotation. Adding the `transform shape` option seems to do the trick but then the text is rotated and scaled... As an ugly workaround, you can draw the node a first time in white. You will still have issues with scaling though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\test#1{%
  \node[white,circle,draw,transform shape](#1) at (0,0) {#1};
  \node[circle,draw] at (0,0) {#1};%
  \draw[->] (#1) edge[in=40,out=-40,loop] ();%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \test{A}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)},rotate=90]
    \test{B}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: In fact, every coordinates are not affected by the rotation except the `in` angle for the start of the loop. But even the control points are placed as if the start of the loop was not rotated. But they are computed using start point+vector and the vector is rotated (?!). This tikz/pgf behaviour seems not right to me.